# Sending Files via Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, file-upload

I'm writing some code so I can connect to my remote machine. I'm using sockets. My machine runs files with the *.hex extension. It reloads .hex files every 10 seconds.

I'm creating a loop program with C# so it sends *.hex files every 10 seconds.

The problem is, how can I send files using socket?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`BeginSendFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginsendfile.aspx) method.

Comment: I send it. But, how i can save it directly ? The machine cant process socket information. How i send to the right directory ? Or Drive ?

Comment: @Aditya You have to manage that sort of thing yourself. There needs to be a program running on your remote machine that's listening to socket connections and accepting your file.